# iTunes: Build (and auto-update) library from external folder

Tags: sync, itunes

I'd like to have my iTunes library automatically synchronise with a folder on an external hard drive. At present, I can add a folder to iTunes, but if I then add new music to this folder, it doesn't show up in iTunes unless I manually drop the files into iTunes. Similarly, music that I've deleted doesn't automatically get removed from iTunes.

I understand that there is a 'Automatically Add to iTunes' folder, but the folder that I'd like to use is not on my internal hard drive.

Are there any solutions out there that will force iTunes to compile its library based on the contents of a folder that is not located on the computer itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use the iTunes `Automatically Add to iTunes` folder.

**Option 1:**

You can create an iTunes library that is on your external drive; I have several stored on mine.

[image]

1. Hold the shift key down when you open iTunes, and you'll get a menu allowing you to create a new library where-ever you want.

**Option 2:**

If you have a partition that is dedicated to your music, you can mount that partition as a folder instead of a letter drive. Just choose the iTunes `Automatically Add to iTunes` folder as the mount point. The folder must currently be empty though.

[image: mount point]

1. Open `Disk Management`, and find your music partition.
2. Right click on it, and choose `change letter drives and paths`.
3. Remove the current letter assigned to it.
4. Right click on it, and choose `change letter drives and paths`.
5. Click `Add`, and then choose `Mount in the following empty NTFS folder`. Browse for the iTunes auto add folder.

Comment: As mentioned above, I am aware of the 'Automatically Add to iTunes' folder, but this does not work for me, as my music library is located on external media

Comment: @CaptainProg I'm fully aware you have your music on an external media, and my answer gives 2 ways of using the external music with the `Automatically Add to iTunes` folder.

Comment: Sorry, the above messsage wasn't meant to send! Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

*> Similarly, music that I've deleted doesn't automatically get removed from iTunes.*

http://ottodestruct.com/itunes/RemoveDeadTracks.txt

Remember, when you save it ... call it RemoveDeadTracks.js

This will remove the dead tracks (!) from your iTunes Media List.